# How to remove repetitive rows from kartik GridView?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

Is it possible to remove repetitive rows from Kartik `GridView`. The table have repetitive data. But I don't want to show them all in grid. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by repetitive rows? and put some code that you have done so far. If you have only one row then you can use detail view.

Comment: may be you need to revise your query that you are using to display the data in gridview

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MuhammadOmerAslam and MjM. Solved the issue. The problem was with my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @muhammad-omer-aslam said you should check your query to remove duplicated rows, maybe using a GROUP BY or a DISTINCT on your desired columns.

Kartik GridView cannot automagically do this for you.